# Example of non-simple 3-D shape

Tags: geometry

Are there any shapes that are co monly known that are also non-simple polytopes in $d=3$?A 3-D 8 would be non simple, correct?

Comment: First, define "simple polytope".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polytope), a simple polyhedron any polyhedron with vertices not adjacent to three edges. Octahedra, icosahedra, and pyramids (with base a square or larger) are all nonsimple, then.

They provide a fairly complete list of simple polyhedra.

Comment: I understand the definition of a simple polyhedra, but I am having trouble finding some kind of common shape that is a non-simple polyhedra.

Comment: @Larry I already gave examples in my answer: octahedra, icosahedra, and pyramids (other than tetrahedra).